# Init method only called once c#

Tags: c#, init

Well, I know this has been asked already and I also happen to know the easiest way to do so.

Now my question is more about your advice on if there is a better way.

I want my method to be called only once when the component is enabled or created.
See I can create a component but keep it disabled, then when I enable it for the first time, I want the Init method to be called. The component is contained into an "attached" object.

So I have the Component with

```
internal bool _runOnce;
```

then I have  the MainObject

```
List<Component> _listComp = new List<Component>();
void Update(){
   foreach(Component c in _listComp){
      if(!c.enable)continue;
      if(c._runOnce){
          c.Init();
          c._runOnce = false;
      }
      c.Update();
   }
}
```

My main concern is that the check for _runOnce will happen every frame for every component on each object. I know it is just a boolean check and is worth nothing but I am just asking if anyone would know a pattern for this purpose that is better than this.

Thanks

Comment: Advice: Don't name public class variables starting with an '_'

Comment: @Kevin Me too thought to give same advice but it may be private variable and OP may be in `Component`

Comment: @SriramSakthivel If that were the case why would he call it Component and MainObject?

Comment: @Kevin I missed that. you're right

Comment: Yes it should be internal.

Comment: Do you always need to run `c.Update();` on ALL components?

Comment: As for running Update on all components, yes, components are scripts created by the user or some of the factory classes. The Update is required to perform all kind of actions. An Update can be empty, but for the sake of the framework it still has to be called.

Comment: @fafase According to your code, `update()` does not need to be called if the `Component` is not enabled, but *does* need to be called otherwise (even for run-once `Components`.) Is that correct?

Comment: Well, the component is created and attached to the GameObject. Then, the GameObject runs the Update of each Component atta0ched to it, if the Component is disabled, no Update is run, all others are run.

Comment: When you Enable the component, why not call Init then?

Comment: Because you can run the component and then disable it but enable it again, that would call Init again.

Comment: Sure... if `Disable` uninits the object, then the object should set `_isInitialized =false` on itself, and its `Init` should then run again and turn it back true.... If it's not, then `Init` should check `_isInitialized` and return without doing any work... If that becomes too expensive for your update loop, it can be revisited but makes for cleaner easier to read code in your update loop.

Comment: If you want something to happen only once in the lifetime of an object you need some code that is actually related to the lifetime of the object. The only candidates are the constructor or maybe an event that gets fired on creation. Since you don't want to initialize before the component is enabled for the first time all possible candidates have already been executed. Hence you must keep track of initalization yourself (using the `_runOnce` field). The only choice left is **when** to do the check: on **each update** or on **each enabling** of the component.

Comment: @pescolino, you should turn that into answer if you want the upvote. I realize what you say totally make sense. I could have the enable boolean to be a property that trigger the init using the same _runOnce principle in the property hence calling only when the component gets enabled. Thanks

Comment: i am thinking the same question but seem like no actual answer

Answer (score 2):

You could also make a list of only the components thats are enabled....

```
List<Component> _listEnabled = _listComp.Where(item => (item.enable == true));

foreach(Component c in _listEnabled ){
   if(c._runOnce){
      c.Init();           // if at all possible, _runOnce should be set to false
      c._runOnce = false; // IN THE OBJECT, after calling Init();
   }
   c.Update();
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't Linq make everything slower? I would guess the first line is within the method so it means I get Linq every frame for every object which does not sound like a good idea. If you meant to have it outside the class, then it would miss all non yet created components. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Linq's going to create a second list of only `Components` that are enabled. There's no sense having them be part of the loop, if you're going to just `continue` and not even need to update() them anyway.

Comment: I'm just scared that if I have hundreds objects that may hurts the speed. I will still try it and see what it gives. I would think this is suitable for a program where speed is not so much of an issue, I am dealing with a game so it might not be suitable.

Comment: @fafase I just realized something... if the flag _runOnce is supposed to only allow a Component to run a single time, shouldn't it set `enable` to false after running it?

Comment: Not to run once, just to call Init once. _runOnce is linked to the Init method and nothing else.

Comment: The _listEnabled filter would be better performance-wise if it was using deferred-evaluation .... but would then equate to doing `if (!c.enable)continue;`

Comment: `Find` does not return a list. It returns the first element that matches the condition. It should be `Where`. And also: why do you think that the check is faster then? It still does the check for each element. This only adds some extra work to create another list.

Comment: @pescolino Wow... how the heck did nobody else see the Find() bug? Ugh. Thanks for the catch. As far as optimization, I'd be curious to benchmark processing a pre-filtered list vs. stepping through each element in a complete list and branching if the condition isn't met. I'm going to theorize that both methods are going to produce nearly the same cycle-time until you hit a sufficiently large list, at which point, preprocessing wins. But again, I'd love some actual benchmark data.

Answer (score 1):

I would question whether `Update()` is the appropriate lifecycle design to `Init()` your dynamic components.

It seems that it would make more sense to have a method notionally called `GameObject.ActivateComponent(AbstractComponent C)` call `C.Init()`, and `AbstractComponent::Init` call `OnInit`, which is what the components override and implement. `AbstractComponent::Init` would make the _runonce check and early-return. It's a method call, but it makes the code more abstract, and has the option to be extended to have a `OnReinitialize` code path later if you need to provide hooks for 'this is the second or later time I was init'd'. (Say, a statistics reset option...)

It definitely seems wrong for `Update()` to be probing an implementation detail like "runonce" to find out about the initialization state of `Component`.

```
List<Component> _listComp = new List<Component>();
void Update(){
   foreach(Component c in _listComp){
  c.Update();
   }
}
```

AbstractComponent

```
 public bool Enable { get;set;}
 private bool _initialized = false;

 void Update(){
     if (!Enable) return;
     Init();
     OnUpdate();
 }

 protected virtual void OnUpdate()
 {
 // filled in by user script
 }

 private void Init()
 {
 if (_initialized) return;
 OnInit();
 _initialized = true;
 }

 protected virtual void OnInit()
 {
 // filled in by user script
 }
```

Comment: also note that what I'm calling `AbstractComponent` may be implemented as `Component` in your game model

Comment: I was about to say, yes it is. Component could be an abstract class from which user created script are inheriting. As for : "and has the option to be extended to have a OnReinitialize code path later if you need to provide hooks for 'this is the second or later time I was init'd'" There will not be any second init. That is the point of this, only called once at the beginning, never again.

Comment: editing to add a notional design that moves this responsibility where it belongs....

Comment: Thanks for your time.Happens to be that your second proposed answer is pretty much rewriting what I already have. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Until profiling showed it was the wrong answer, I'd probably stick with that design then... Optimizing from what I expect on minute inspection to be callvirts versus local field lookups seems like it'd not make things better, but it'd take profiling of a real scenario to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

`My main concern is that the check for _runOnce will happen every frame for every component on each object.`

From that I assume that you call `Update` very frequently. My concerns would be for the `Update` method of the components which is very likely to be much more expensive than a boolean check. This is called micro-optimization: You put a lot of effort into something that isn't a problem at all.

However, I would suggest to encapsulate initialization. Your `MainObject` does not need to know anything about it. `_runOnce` should be a private member of the component and `enable` should be a property (btw: `_runOnce` should be initialized to true somewhere). Each time your component is enabled you can check for `_runOnce` and call the initialization if needed:

```
public class MyComponent
{
    private bool _isInitialized; // I think this is a better name than _runOnce
    private bool _enable;

    public bool Enable
    {
        get
        {
            return _enable;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_enable == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (value == true && !_isInitialized)
            {
                Init();
            }

            _enable = value;
        }
    }

    private void Init()
    {
        // initialization logic here ...

        _isInitialized = true;
    }
}
```

Another idea would be to defer initialization to the `Update` method. This is basically what you already have but in an object oriented design:

```
public void Update()
{
    if (_enable && !_isInitialized)
    {
        Init();
    }

    // update logic here ...
}
```

Comment: I realized your answer is not fixing the issue. Either I used the property pattern and that fixes the issue when the activation is set for later but if the component is meant to be active right from creation then I am back with initial setup. Or I have to make the call from the Component ctor which does not sound suitable...

Comment: @fafase: If the component is active right from creation the value of the property will still be set to true somewhere. As long as it is set using the property (not the backing field) the initialization will be called anyway.

Answer (score 0):

What about just a regular constructor for Component?

```
public Component()
{
   Init();
}
```

Comment: Because a Component can be created but left disabled. This way it would call the method on creation. See it is for a game object, so you may have all kind of Component attached to the GO, but maybe some of them are just waiting and are inactive.

Comment: Well you can add the check for enabled in the constructor...  but I'm confused.. can the component start disabled and then become enabled?  Then what triggers the call to init?

Comment: Yes the Component can be attached to the GameObject as a setup but kept inactive until something wakes it up. That is when the Init should be called and only then. No more later.

Comment: then shouldn't the 'wake it up' operation call `Init()`, and not `Update()`?

Comment: In this case, I would have an Init method in the GO that does pretty much the same thing happening in the Update, checking for the boolean and then run if necessary, just somewhere else.